# Simple input class change with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, event-handling, dom

I am just testing how I solved simple stuff.

**Goal:** The aim is to expand the width of an `input` and collapse it.

When `mouseover` expand,.

When `mouseout` collapse.

When you have text inside the `input` keep it expanded.

---

To me it seems too much, repeating some stuff in JS.
Also thought about adding a debouncer or throttle but was not successful.

There's probably another way to solve it with pure CSS.

HTML:

```
<body>
<p>
    2 inputs, 1 is collapsed 
    the other is expanded

</p>    
<br>
collapsed   
<br>
    <input type="text" class="collapsed">
    <br>
    <br>
    expanded
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="expanded">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    width: 20px;
    transition: width 1s;
}

.expanded{
    width: 256px;
}
```

JS:

```
let collapsedInput = document.querySelector('.collapsed');

const handleMouseOut = () => {
    collapsedInput.classList.remove('expanded');
}

const handleMouseOVer = () => {
    collapsedInput.classList.add('expanded');
}

collapsedInput.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseOVer);

collapsedInput.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut);

collapsedInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if(collapsedInput.value !== ""){
        collapsedInput.classList.add('expanded');
        collapsedInput.removeEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut);
    } else {
        collapsedInput.classList.remove('expanded');
        collapsedInput.addEventListener('mouseout', handleMouseOut);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Review

The biggest critique about the Javascript I have is that `collapsedInput` could be declared with `const` because it doesn't get re-assigned.

It is possible that the code in the event listener for the `input` event could be simplified using `classList.toggle()`.

If there is only one element with class name `collapsed` then perhaps it would be better to use an `id` attribute and use `document.getElementById()` to select it. Those older methods [are faster than the `querySelector()` varieties](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/280663/2).

### Dramatic simplification

The question contained this text:

> There's probably another way to solve it with pure CSS.

That is correct. One way is to use the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required) attribute on the first `<input>` element along with the [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) and [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) pseudo-selectors :

```css
input {
    width: 20px;
    transition: width 1s;
}

input:valid,
input:hover,
.expanded {
    width: 256px;
}
```

```html
<p>
    2 inputs, 1 is collapsed 
    the other is expanded

</p>    
<br>
collapsed   
<br>
    <input type="text" class="collapsed" required>
    <br>
    <br>
    expanded
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="expanded">
```

Perhaps someday the CSS pseudo-class [`:blank`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank) will be supported by some browsers... If that is the case, then the `required` attribute wouldn't be needed.

Comment: +1 however a very minor point in regard to transitions. 1 second is way too long, 1/5th - 1/3rd second still adds wiz-bang without giving an interface a slow feel

Comment: At the risk of sounding naive, could you explain more about "wiz-bang"? If you have enough for an answer maybe we could get this up to a HNQ...

Comment: wiz-bang as in look good, or slick. Better than no transition at all.